# Robocopy copying unchanged files to other server

Tags: backup, robocopy

I have a problem with a robocopy script that is supposed to mirror a directory including the NTFS ACL from one server to another server.

It seems that even though no files have changed, the complete content is copied every time.

This is the command I am using

> robocopy \\abc.com\original \\otherserver\mirrordir /XD _MirrorLogs /MIR /COPY:DATS /R:2 /W:2 /LOG+:\abc.com\logfile.LOG /TEE

This is the result (extracts) I am getting

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Started : Wed Jun 12 23:00:19 2013

Source : \\abc.com\original\
Dest : \\otherserver\mirrordir\

Files : *.*

Exc Dirs : _MirrorLogs

Options : *.* /TEE /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DATS /PURGE /MIR /R:2 /W:2 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...

                   2    \\abc.com\original\Best_Practices\
            7223    file1.html
          194048    file2.doc
                   3    \\abc.com\original\_history\
          155194    file3.xlsm
    New File              159091    file4.xlsm
  0%  
 20%  
 41%  
 61%  
 82%  
100%  
    New File          155222    file5.xlsm
  0%  
 21%  
 42%  
 63%  
 84%  
100%  

...

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :       422         0       422         0         0         0
Files :      3123      3123         0         0         0         0
Bytes :  649.27 m  649.27 m         0         0         0         0
Times :   0:56:17   0:52:18                       0:00:00   0:03:58


Speed :              216918 Bytes/sec.
Speed :              12.412 MegaBytes/min.

Ended : Wed Jun 12 23:56:38 2013
```

I can understand that when there is the tag "New File" that this needs to be copied. Okay.
What I also understand is that no Dirs are copied according to the summary. This is what I expected.
What I don't understand is that it seems that all files were copied again, even though there were no changes. Most of the files look like file1.html, file2.doc and file3.xlsm, i.e. there is no information why the file is copied (like New File or Newer).
I checked with Beyond Compare if the files are identical, and from the content point of view they are. I thought about different access rights, but then why does the problem not occur in case of the directories (where the access rights were also copied).

Does anyone have a hint for me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that when `robocopy` is copying these folders from one server to another, I suspect that it is seeing the timestamps differently than you expect, so it is deciding that the existing files on the destination are older than the same files on the source. This could be due to differences in the time/timezone/DST settings on the two machines.

When `robocopy` analyzes the files before copying, it classifies each file into one of these classes:

```
Lonely files:  exist on source but not destination.
Newer files:   have Newer timestamp on source, (size and attributes: N/A).
Older files:   have Older timestamp on source, (size and attributes: N/A).
Changed files: have same timestamp, but different size (attributes: N/A).
Same files:    have same timestamp, size, and attributes.
Tweaked files: have same timestamp and size, but different attributes.
Extra files:   exist on destination but not source.
Mismatched:    is a file on one, and a directory on the other, in source
               and destination.
```

By default (and with the command line options you have given), `robocopy` will copy `Lonely`, `Newer`, and `Changed` files. Files in the other classes will ***not*** be copied, and will either be simply reported in the output and/or log, or completly ignored.

If `robocopy` is copying a file and overwriting an existing file on the destination, then `robocopy` thinks that either the timestamo of the source file is before (`Newer`) the timestamp of the  destination file, or the file sizes are different (`Changed`).

In order to tell exactly what's happening to each file, you could run `robocopy` with the `"/L"` and `"/V"` command line options. Using the `"/L"` options tells `robocopy` to not do any actual copying, and only list what would otherwise be copied. Using the `"/V"` options tells `robocopy` to to provide ***Verbose*** details.

This will show ***why*** `robocopy` has decided to copy (and skip) each file. So, for example using `robocopy` to copy an example fileset.

Here is a listing of the files:

```
 Directory of C:\folder1

02/28/2014  12:48 PM               327 File1.txt
02/28/2014  02:03 PM               333 File2.txt
               2 File(s)            660 bytes

 Directory of C:\folder2

02/28/2014  12:43 PM               327 File1.txt
02/28/2014  02:03 PM               327 File2.txt
               2 File(s)            654 bytes
```

In this example, the files named `File1.txt`, are the same size in the source and destination folders, but has a `Newer` timestamp in `Folder1`. And, the files named `File2.txt`, have the same timestamp in the source and destination folders, but have different (`Changed`) file sizes.

Running `robocopy` to copy `Folder1` to `Folder2`, with the `"/L"` and `"/V"` command line options looks like this.

```
C:\>robocopy "C:folder1" "c:folder2" /E /L /V

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Fri Feb 28 21:07:29 2014

   Source : C:\folder1\
     Dest : C:\folder2\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /V /L /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           2    C:\folder1\
            Newer                    327        File1.txt
            Changed                  333        File2.txt

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         2         2         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :       660       660         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

   Ended : Fri Feb 28 21:07:29 2014
```

If you run `robocopy` with the `"/L"` and `"/V"` command line options on your set of files, it should give you the information of why `robocopy` is unexpectedly copying these files.

I suspect that `robocopy` is seeing the timestamps differently than you expect, and is deciding that the files on the source are `Newer` than the same existing files on the destination. This could be due to differences in the time/timezone/DST settings on the two machines.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Try the `/FFT` switch to handle small timestamp differences.

---

I was having the same issue as you: files were being copied by robocopy even though they were unchanged between the source and destination.

The other posted answer is helpful, but even running robocopy with `/L` and `/v` just kind of tells you what you already know (that robocopy thinks the source file is different than the destination).

Robocopy uses timestamp attributes and file size to determine whether a file should be copied or not. In my case the file sizes were the same, but the timestamps were differing by 1 second. Apparently this is not uncommon when copying to remote file systems, especially when they're not NTFS.

It turns out that robocopy has a switch to handle the problem: `/FFT`

> /FFT uses fat file timing instead of NTFS. This means the granularity is a bit less precise. For across-network share operations this seems to be much more reliable - just don't rely on the file timings to be completely precise to the second. -- [Robocopy and a Few Examples](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing found on Google with regards to tweaking the Robocopy parameters worked for my Robocopy job repeating the copy of files from an NTFS network mapped drive (SharePoint folder) to a USB drive.

Neither did reformatting the USB to NTFS. What did ultimately do it was downloading the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit from Microsoft and then extracting the `robocopy.exe` from that (by opening the `rktools.exe` in a zip program) and rewriting just the two lines that do the robocopy job from the network drives with this older version.

The parameters needed to be tweaked a little as some did not function in the older version. It looks to me like the new Robocopy in Windows 10 has a bug.

Did not work:

`Robocopy.exe I: D:\Network_Backups\ /MIR /TEE /FFT /DST /TIMFIX /W:5 /R:5 /NP / LOG+:D:\Robocopy\LOG.txt`

Worked:

`D:\Robocopy\Robocopy2003.exe I: D:\Network_Backups\ /MIR /XO /TEE /FFT /W:1 /R:2 /NP /LOG+:D:\Robocopy\LOG.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make this work with Copying Online Only to DropBox and had tried /XA:O without success.  I tried the 2003RK copy of Robocopy (which I've hung onto for years because it solves weird problems) and sure enough it does the trick.   Thank you Chip!  I can't UpVote, but really want to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).